# Proof of identity $E[V | W] = E[E[V | U,W] | W]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

What is the intuition and the proof behind the expression

$E[V | W] = E[E[V | U,W] | W]$

where $U,V,W$ are random variables. I know that $E[V | W]$ can be treated as a random variable which is a function of $W$ but I am having a hard time getting the intuition about the above expression of nested expectations.

Comment: I think it should be $$E[V \mid W]=E[E[V\mid U] \mid W]$$

Comment: When $V$ is square integrable, this says that, for some vector subspaces $J\subset K$ of $L^2(P)$ that I will let you discover, the associated orthogonal projections $\pi_J$ and $\pi_K$ are such that $\pi_J=\pi_J\circ\pi_K$.

Comment: @JimmyR. Your suggestion makes the exercise wrong, in fact, $E(E(V\mid U)\mid W)$ need not be $E(V\mid W)$ except if $W$ is $\sigma(U)$-measurable.

Comment: This claim appears in "Probability and Computing" by Mitzenmacher and Upfal (2nd edition), on page 342 (Martingales chapter, second page). Unfortunately, it is given as a fact justified by Definition 2.7, which reads: "The expression $E[Y|Z]$ is a random variable $f(Z)$ that takes on the value $E[Y | Z = z]$ when $Z=z$".

Comment: For the sake of contextualization, you could say that you're trying to understand the characterization of Doob martingales, where this identity is needed.